# Magento 2 External URL button in admin order

Tags: admin, orders, magento2.3.5, custom-button

I made a custom button in sales->orders.
[image]

Which should direct to another external url([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)).

In my app/code/vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales i have: CustomButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;


class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * CustomButton constructor.
     *
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
 

        return [
            'label' => __('Custom Button'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl('www.google.com', []);
    }
}
```

and in view/adminhtml/ui_component i have sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="CustomButton" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\CustomButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

When i click the custom button to go [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) i get:
[image]

Could use some pointers on how to achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try This**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;


class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * CustomButton constructor.
     *
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {


        return [
            'label' => __('Custom Button'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href ='https://www.google.com/'"),
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 50
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks alot it works! any idea on how can i make it so it opens in a new tab?

Comment: i got it myself i used parent.open() and it seems to do the trick. Thanks again tho.